# Case assignment rules on customer community using Napilli template

Tags: customer-community, assignment-rules

The case assignment rules don't fire when the case is created via the customer community when it is set up using the pre-defined Napili template.

On the old portal the 'Show Case Assignment' checkbox needed to be displayed but there seems to be no way to show this on the Napili template?  All that the community template docs say is:

> Create a case assignment rule so that cases created from your
>   community are assigned to your support agents. For more information on
>   case assignment rules, see the Salesforce Help.

Any ideas on how to make the standard assignment rules work with these templates?  The assignment rule works ok when I run it internally for example and yes I can use both triggers and workflow but neither are as flexible as the assignment rule.

Comment: Have you sorted your problem?
I have followed these instructions:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005470&language=en_US
but it doesn't seem to work either.